# Javascript function is not getting called onclick of hx:commandExButton

Tags: javascript, jsf, ibm-jsf

When I click on the `hx:commandExButton` the Javascript function should get called, but it is not getting called. The Javascript function is as follows:

```
function test() {
    alert('ss');
    return  "true";
}
```

The `hx:commandButton` is as follows:

```
<hx:commandExButton
    type="submit"
    value="Search"
    styleClass="action2" id="searchButton"
    onclick="return test();"
    action="#{pc_WorkInProgressUserGrid.doSearchButtonAction}"
    immediate="true">
</hx:commandExButton>
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Where does this component `commandExButton` comes from?

Comment: What is the actual HTML output of this?

Comment: @romaintaz: It comes from the IBM Faces Client Framework. A buggy and poorly documented JSF component library which is included in WSAD/RAD.

Comment: hello Everyone ,
i am developing a school project ,in that there is a jsp page and this jsp page has table with 2 columns onpage load begin of this jsp first column will be populated with list of teachers
question here is
this included jsp will have 3 columns one column has name of the class second column has number of students attended yesterday and third column will have text box to enter number of students attended todays class

here the number classes a teacher handles per day is different for every teacher can some please help me how to create a dynamic table in the included JSP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step would be to check the generated HTML output to verify if it looks right. It may for instance happen that the `hx:commandExButton` itself didn't take the `onclick` attribute value correctly into account. As a test, you could try to get rid of it and use the standard JSF `h:commandButton` instead.

Further I also recall something about a crazy `<hx:scriptCollector>` tag which you are supposed to wrap the piece of JSF code with whenever you'd like to use Javascript in combination with IBM Faces Client components.

E.g.

```
<hx:scriptCollector id="someid">
    <hx:form>
       <hx:commandExButton />
    </hx:form>
</hx:scriptCollector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JSF, but it's immediately obvious that you have omitted a " after true, and also a >

Are those ** supposed to be there? And writing method before a function is definitely not part of standard JavaScript.

Comment: I've edited his post, but I don't think this is his problem, otherwise the button would not even be displayed in his page...